# How to set up a default operation whenever a catch block get executed?

Tags: java, catch-block

For debugging purposes i want my Java application to upload a log file on my `MySql` database whenever a `catch` clause is executed, regardless of which exception is thrown.

The worst solution i thought to was to add my uploader method into each `catch` in my code (as I already did for the creation of my log file) . This is obviously not elegant method, as long it's repeated code. So my question is: it exist someway (maybe in project proprieties) to set a default operation to be executed whenever a `catch` clause is met?

Comment: Use a logging framework like Log4J. No need to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: You can put the bulk of your code that writes the log message to mysql in its own method, and call that method in each catch block, just like how you'd print the stacktrace when developing smaller projects. To my knowledge, there is no way to say "do this every time a catch clause is met".

Comment: @Matt that was exatly what i wanted to avoid as long my application may generate many and different exceptions. @PM 77-1 Ye, i read about Log4J but my final choice was the simpler `java.util.logging.Logger` to handle the log file. Is it possible also with my logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a logging framework (no matter if you write this your self or use an existing solution), so you can do:

```
try{}
catch(Exception e) {Logger.logExceptionToDatabase(e); }
```

In this you could handle the upload into your database. However I do not thinkt that it is very useful to upload error logs into your database each time a `catch` block gets executed. I would write them to seperate text logs and collect them and only persist them to a database from time to time or by user request.

To the question itself: This is not possible, however there is a `finally` block which gets executed after the according `try` block (as long as the JVM is not terminated within the try block). Maybe you could introduce some `TransactionResult` and do a logging for each success and failure and than do:

```
TransactionResult transactionResult;

try{
//do work and at the last line in the try after each operation that could 
have failed has been executed set your transactionResult variable
transactionResult = new SuccessTransaction();
}
catch(Excpetion e) { transactionResult=  new FailureTransaction();}
finally {Logger.logTransaction(transactionResult); }
```

and the according classes:

```
public interface TransactionResult{
  public void writeLog();

}
```

and an example of an transaction result:

```
public class SuccessTransaction implements TransactionResult{
private String resultStatus;

public SuccessTransaction() { this.resultStatus = "success"; }

public void writeLog() { System.out.println(this.resultStatus); } //or whatever you want to do with your result

}
```

same goes for your failure instance.

**Update**

As you stated that there are many Exceptions, you could also pass your Exception to your concrete `FailureTransaction` and than simply write that message out or collect all the failures in a list and then you can trace which exceptions have been triggered.

Comment: "To the question itself: This is not possible"; actually you can execute common code "whenever a catch clause is executed, regardless of which exception is thrown" by simply having a generic `catch (Exception e)`  as you do, or even a multi-catch `catch (FooException | BarException | BazException e)`. By catching any exception with one clause op can avoid repeating code and just handle them all there, which is their main concern. If a specific exception needs to be handled after the common handling, then op can re-throw and catch the specific exception.

Comment: I underatood the question that way that he wants a "fixed" and general way to Do this or even a Java keyword that does this so I tried to provide a useable solution. Also I tried to be as clean as possible since imho there is nothing worse than exception handling so this must be nice and clean :) The general Exception of course must be replaces with the closest one available to the catch block. I will update the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, I see. I understood it as op wanting to avoid the repeated code from copy pasting the logging code into the multiple catch clauses.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to create a default behavior without typing it into it... Create a global method so you can call it with one line.

Comment: I disagree, you can catch generic Exceptions, thus making a "default" behavior for any type of exception.

Comment: I believe the op was trying to ask for a way to write the "default" behavior only once at the beginning of their program, and have any try/catch blocks run that code if the catch is entered, without typing anything with regards to it, like some property that says (for all catch blocks, do this: ...) or something like that. This is what Thiago is answering. What you are describing @xtratic is exactly what the op is trying to avoid

Comment: @Matt Yikes, that sounds like a terrible idea, I really hope that's not what Op was actually asking for..

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
public static void myMethod() throws FooException, BarException   {
    throw new FooException();
}

// if you don't care about specific catch cases:
public static void main(String[] args) throws FooException, BarException   {
    try {
        myMethod();
    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace(); // default behavior on exception
        throw x; // let the specific exception bubble up the call stack 
        // The compiler knows that this will be either FooException or BarException
    }
}

// if you need to also handle specific catch cases:
public static void main(String[] args) throws BarException {
    try { // outer try-catch, to handle specific exceptions
        try { // inner try-catch to handle default catch behavior
            myMethod();
        } catch (Exception x) { // Or } catch (FooException | BarException   x) {
            x.printStackTrace(); // default behavior on exception
            throw x; // let the exception bubble up to the specific catch clauses.
            // The compiler knows that this will be either FooException or BarException
        }
    } catch (FooException e) {
        System.err.println("Doing something specific to 'FooException'");
        // could re-throw if you want to
    } catch (BarException  e) {
        System.err.println("Doing something specific to 'BarException'");
        throw e; // only re-throw if you want to
    }
}
```

If you don't need to do anything for specific exceptions then the first `main` should work just fine.

If you do want to handle specific exceptions *on top of your default catch behavior*, then just re-throw the exception, catch what it is specifically, and handle that specific case.

You can always re-throw the exception when you want it to bubble further up the call stack.